# Iterate State in redux using dynamic tokens

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I need to dynamically iterate through the state with the help of a json file. For example I need to lookup username from state which looks something like this :

customer.product.name.username

And i need the name and username part to be dynamically populated from a json file.

Can someone please help in giving me some pointers how can this be achieved?

I have tried template literals but it was not fitting my requirement. Or maybe i am not using it correctly.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Question would be more clear if we could see some code. And easier to give a solution as well